# find Uncommon element in Secod arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

```
int[] arr1 = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
        int[] arr2 = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2.Length; j++)
            {
                if (arr1[i] == arr2[j])
                {
                    //Console.Write(arr1[i]);
                }

            }
        }
```

Output of above code:

5,4,2,1

I want output:

3

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Except` method

```
arr1.Except(arr2);
```

Also, to find common elements, you can use the `Intersect` method:

```
arra1.Intersect(arr2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) method to find the difference of two sequences:

```
foreach(var item in arr1.Except(arr2))
    Console.Write(item);
```

---

If you are not allowed to use LINQ, then simply check if second array contains item from first array

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
    if (!arr2.Contains(arr1[i]))
        Console.WriteLine(arr1[i]);
}
```

Comment: not to use any buildin function  like except,diff etc ..Thanks for your time

Comment: @MashalJabeen see my update, but keep in mind that LINQ is more efficient in this case

Comment: @ofstream can you give an example of array which will not work? BTW there is no requirements for distinct output

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Sorry, my fault, misread the title. Could you please edit the answer just a bit to remove my downvote?

Comment: @ofstream sure, made an edit

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Fixed. Sorry!